# How to get name and values from a javascript object into a new list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, select

I have this JavaScript object which is a collection of multiple lists(I believe). I need to create a select dropdown with the name being the name of the list, and a number of boxes with background color as per that name. Like this:

[image: final result example]

I am able to parse that object to get all the names of the colors, but I can't find a way to parse the names and the list of values it holds. This is how I tried :

```
var
    YlGn3 = ['#f7fcb9', '#addd8e', '#31a354'],
    YlGn4 = ['#ffffcc', '#c2e699', '#78c679', '#238443'],
    YlGn5 = ['#ffffcc', '#c2e699', '#78c679', '#31a354', '#006837'];

var brewer = Object.freeze({
    YlGn3: YlGn3,
    YlGn4: YlGn4
});

var office = Object.freeze({
    YlGn5: YlGn5
});

var colorschemes = {
    brewer: brewer,
    office: office
};

var scheme_list = [];

for (i in colorschemes){
 for(j in colorschemes[i]){
  console.log(j);
  scheme_list.push(j);
 }
}
```

I was thinking of creating a new object and append every color, along with the list of colors, so I can parse it again to create an option element with it. But, I am not able to figure out the best way to do that. Is this the correct approach ?

Comment: what is `export_colors`?

Comment: My bad, it's ```colorschemes```. Edited.

Comment: Why can't you put all the arrays into one array and loop over that? `const colors = [YlGn3, YlGn4, YlGn3]; colors.forEach(arr=>arr.forEach(c=>{}))`

Comment: @hev1 Actually the thing is, the top part where all the colors are defined are coming from a third party js file, and hence cannot be changed.

Comment: "Is this the correct approach ?" Do you get expected result?

Comment: @RohitKumar Do you need to use `colorschemes`? If not, the approach I described above is easier.

Comment: @JanStránský I got the names, so I think I am going the correct direction, but not sure how to get the list of colors, along with the name. If it were a simple key value pair like in python, this would have been easier. But I am new to JS.
@hev1 Yes I have to use it the variable ```colorschemes``` as is.

Comment: please edit the question to contain the desired result, then it would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Object.values` along with `forEach` multiple times.

```
Object.values(colorschemes).forEach(obj=>Object.entries(obj).forEach(([name,colors])=>{
  const arr = [];
  colors.forEach(color=>arr.push(color));
  scheme_list.push([name, arr]);
}));
```

```js
var
    YlGn3 = ['#f7fcb9', '#addd8e', '#31a354'],
    YlGn4 = ['#ffffcc', '#c2e699', '#78c679', '#238443'],
    YlGn5 = ['#ffffcc', '#c2e699', '#78c679', '#31a354', '#006837'];

var brewer = Object.freeze({
    YlGn3: YlGn3,
    YlGn4: YlGn4
});

var office = Object.freeze({
    YlGn5: YlGn5
});

var colorschemes = {
    brewer: brewer,
    office: office
};

var scheme_list = [];
Object.values(colorschemes).forEach(obj=>Object.entries(obj).forEach(([name,colors])=>{
  const arr = [];
  colors.forEach(color=>arr.push(color));
  scheme_list.push([name, arr]);
}));
console.log(scheme_list);
```

Comment: Good sir, we get each and every color value here, but I want the color value and the name of the colorscheme. I found a way to either get the names only, or every color only. But my issue is to get both of them. I will update my question to clearly ask what format I want at the end.

Comment: @RohitKumar Updated my answer.